# Map levels of factor

Tags: r, dictionary, r-factor

How to map the levels of a factor by a reference vector or list?

```
  a<-factor(sample(1:3,20,T))
  b<-c("1"="B","2"="C","3"="A")
  levels(a)<-list("1"="B","2"="C","3"="A")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this???

```
> set.seed(1)
> a<-factor(sample(1:3,20,T))
> factor(a, levels=c(3,1,2), labels=c("A", "B", "C"))
 [1] B C C A B A A C C B B B A C A C A A C A
Levels: A B C
```

See `?factor` for further details.

Comment: Is there any function how to map in general, e.g. `a<-LETTERS[1:4]` and the reference vector is `b<-c("A"=5,B="2",D=3)`?

Comment: isn't `factor` general enough? what do you  mean with a general function?

Comment: e.g. if you want to change the colnames of a data.frame in the same way, to find for each column name the new name in the reference vector.